# password issue in cloning git repository from bitbucket

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I have bitbucket git repository.
I tried to clone it from my PC, but I cannot give password.

```
git clone https://id@bitbucket.org/id/SOMEGITPROJ.git
Cloning into SOMEGITPROJ...
Password:
```

As I have this error.

```
'PASSWORD' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to solve this issue? Is there any way to give the password in the same command line of 'git clone command'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer in this site:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

**For mac**

In short:

1. `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
2. go to account/ssh keys to add this key
3. use ssh protocol not https

**For PC**

In short:

1. `cat /home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > key.txt`
2. same as Mac

**For Linux**

In short:

1. `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | xclip -sel clip`
2. same as Mac

Comment: id_rsa not id_dsa. I tried to edit but not enough reputation :(