# Bitbucket asking for password to clone repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am cloning a repo on bitbucket from a new computer, but it's asking me for a password. My bitbucket password does not work. Cloning repo's on GitHub works fine. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

This is the error I keep seeing after using my Bitbucket password.

```
remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
```

Comment: Check if it is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107611/password-issue-in-cloning-git-repository-from-bitbucket

Comment: bitbucket is a premium git platform and is more secure. Bitbucket will ask you to enter password for each and every activities like pushing code, cloning,etc

Comment: Perfect. can’t believe I didn’t come across that on my search thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone trying to clone for first time please follow following steps to generate password and store it somewhere so that you can access it later on whenever it's required. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your protocol (https or ssh).

- SSH should not ask you anything unless you have assciated a passphrase to your private key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- HTTPS should allow you to cache your credentials with a credential manager: see "[Permanently authenticating with Git repositories](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html)".
  Check what `git config --global credential.helper` returns.

The [OP jschuss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8728528/jschuss) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219967/bitbucket-asking-for-password-to-clone-repo/48220129#comment83454522_48220129):

> After a lot of trial and error I managed by changing my Atlassian password credentials and it worked

It is possible the previous password had special characters, that would need to be [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data) when cached.
However, the [OP jschuss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8728528/jschuss) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219967/bitbucket-asking-for-password-to-clone-repo/48220129#comment83497965_48220129) it might be a current bug:

> No, my old password did not contain any special characters.
>   But the act of setting a new password/ waiting a few minutes/ using a new terminal window was suggested to me by the support team after I had done it already, so it seems to be something people are dealing with lately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After a lot of trial and error I managed by changing my Atlassian password credentials and it worked. Appreciate the help though

Comment: @jschuss Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Did your old password contain special characters? (space, `%`, `_`, ...)

Comment: Thanks! No my old password did not contain any special characters, but the act of setting a new password/ waiting a few minutes/ using a new terminal window was suggested to me by the support team after I had done it already, so it seems to be something people are dealing with lately.

Comment: @jschuss Thank you for this feedback: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.