# Git asks username and password when cloning a public repo from bitbucket with https

Tags: git, https, bitbucket, clone

I have browsed quite a few similar questions and answers, but none helped, including [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219967/bitbucket-asking-for-password-to-clone-repo), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600652/git-on-bitbucket-always-asked-for-password-even-after-uploading-my-public-ssh) among others.

My problem is when I clone my public bitbucket repo with https

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/JzHuai0108/ceres_catkin.git
```

, git keeps asking for my username and password for bitbucket.

This problem does not occur with another public repo on bitbucket.

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/stash-example-plugin.git
```

So how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The situation is that I just made the repo public, and it took like ten minutes on the server for this to take effect.
The time should be better spent on a break than on googling for an answer to this question :(.